# A function satisfies the identity $f(x) + 2f\left(\frac1x\right) = 2x+1$ ... find another identity that $f(x)$ satisfies.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> A function satisfies the identity $f(x) + 2f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = 2x+1$.
>   By replacing all instances of $x$ with $\frac{1}{x}$, find another identity that $f(x)$ satisfies.

I have absolutely no idea what this question is asking, and how to go about it. I would really appreciate some help; thanks in advance!

Comment: Just replace $x$ with $1/x$ here and compare the new equation with the old one.

Comment: If you would like to be able to post pictures in the future, it is important to note that accepting answers is a means of boosting your reputation. You can do this by clicking the check mark underneath the downvote arrow in the answer you would like to accept.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @BjörnFriedrich!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is asking you to replace a $\frac{1}{x}$ every where you see an $x$ in $f(x) + 2f(1/x) = 2x+1$, i.e. $f(\frac{1}{x})+2f(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}})=f(\frac{1}{x})+2f(x)=\frac{2}{x}+1$.

Comment: Oh wow; much simpler than I thought! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have your original identity and new one obtained by substituting $\frac1x$ instead of $x$:
\begin{align}
f(x)+2f\left(\frac1x\right) &= 2x+1 \tag{1}\\
f\left(\frac1x\right)+2f(x) &= \frac2x+1 \tag{2}
\end{align}
Now you want to combine the two equalities to get $f(x)$. If you add to equation $(1)$ the equation $(2)$ multiplied by $-2$, then the occurrences of $f(1/x)$ cancel each other out:
\begin{align*}
-3f(x) &= 2x-\frac4x-1\\
f(x) &= -\frac23x +\frac4{3x}+\frac13
\end{align*}